# SQL Server : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

User Table:

```
UserID   Username      FirstName    Lastname
1001     KiranReddy    Kiran        Reddy
1002     Arvind        Arvind       Kumar
1003     Arun          Arrun        Swamy
1004     Ramesh        Ramesh       Naidu
1005     Ramesh        Ramesh       Naidu
1006     Ajay1233      Ajay         Sharma
```

Friend Table:

```
UserID1       UserID2
1001          1002
1001          1003
1001          1004
1001          1005
1001          1006
```

How to do following query: I want to get the usernames for users that are friend of user 1001 and username is like 'A%'

Comment: nope, your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Please show your query that raised error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value` ?

Comment: Why you store `UserID1` and `UserID2` as columns in your friend table? Every friend should get it's own record. Now you can never have more than two friends. That's sad.

Comment: not clear enough !

Comment: I think he has a many to many relationship using friend table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select friend.UserID2 from User
left join Friend on friend.userid1 = user.userid
Where user.username like '%A' and friend.UserID1 ='1001'
```

Comment: How will this give `username`s?  It will only give all `userID2`s from the `FriendTable` where they start with an "A"

Comment: The OP asks for  "whose UserID2 username start with 'A%'".  Will your edited answer do that?

Comment: try this now ... it may helps this time

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `UserID2` in your join?

Comment: I think I am the one who wrote the query ! :D

Comment: @BishoyFrank thank you ...its working great...happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.Username 
FROM Friend as f 
INNER JOIN User as u
ON f.UserID2 = u.UserID
WHERE f.UserID1 = '1001'
AND u.Username LIKE "A%"
ORDER BY u.Username
```

That should do it. Of course you could return more than just the Username.

Comment: Please don't promote the use of non-ANSI joins.

Comment: Actually those are ANSI too, old-style.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.Username 
FROM [User] AS u join
     [Friend] as f on f.UserID2 = u.UserID 
     WHERE f.UserID2 = 1001 AND u.Username LIKE 'A%'
```